# Implementing dynamic menu for Spring MVC/AOP application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aop, spring-aop

I wish to implement dynamically changeable menu (updating whenever annotated method or controller added) for my Spring MVC application.

What i want is to introduce new annotation (`@RequestMenuMapping`) which will go to `@Controller` beans and their methods (just like `@RequestMapping` works).

Heres is what i want, `User` class, producing menu like

```
Users
    Index | List | Signup | Login
```

with following code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("user")
@RequestMenuMapping("Users")
public class User {

    @RequestMapping("")
    @RequestMenuMapping("Index")
    public String index(/* no model here - just show almost static page (yet with JSP checks for authority)*/) {
        return "user/index.tile";
    }

    @RequestMapping("list")
    @RequestMenuMapping("List")
    public String list(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("userList",/* get userlist from DAO/Service */);

        return "user/list.tile";
    }

    @RequestMapping("signup")
    @RequestMenuMapping("Signup")
    public String signup(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("user",/* create new UserModel instance to be populated by user via html form */);

        return "user/signup.tile";
    }

    @RequestMapping("login")
    @RequestMenuMapping("Login")
    public String login(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("userCreds",/* create new UserCreds instance to be populated via html form with login and pssword*/);

        return "user/login.tile";
    }
}
```

I think that Spring AOP may help me to pointcut methods with `@RequestMenuMapping` annotation and via `@AfterReturning` add something representing web-site menu to model.

But this raises two questions:

1. How do i get `Model` instance in `@AfterReturning` advice method in case it is missing in adviced method (as in `.index()`)?
2. How do i get all methods (as in java reflection `Method`) and classes (as in java reflection `Class`) annotated with `@RequestMenuMapping` in order to build complete menu index?

Comment: Frankly, I think it's not a good idea. It's more complex than the obvious solution, doesn't support internatioanlized labels, doesn't have any notion of order between the menu items, doesn't support passing any parameter to the URL, etc. etc.

Comment: I disagree. What is obvious solution? It supports internationalized labels just fine - simply treat value() as localization bundle code like `menu.Users.Signup=Зарегестрироваться` and place "Signup" as defaultLabel(). It may use just the order methods defined in class or have additional order() parameter. What do you possibly wish to pass as parameter to the URL? This is all easily implementable. Only two questions in original post are bothering me.

Comment: You've been warned! My guess is that you'll implement a very complex solution, just to be able to display a static menu in the webapp. Instead of just having this static menu in JSP fragment or tag, and to add an item to the menu when a new action is implemented and must appear in the menu.

Comment: What you suggesting is what i already had. It is hard to keep track on all menu items and sync them with application state. Instead, i wish to have ever-synced state of my menu, freeing me of editing both code and JSP menu fragment.

Comment: Your solution is overcomplicated, I would go with a jsp fragment + some DSL-style code that specifies the order of menuitems createMenu().item('menu.usersSignup', 'menuSignup').item('menu.someItem', 'someItem', ROLE_OPERATOR.isGranted()).subMenu('menu.config' ).separator().subMenu('menu.backup',  ROLE_ADMIN.isGranted(), 'backup')..subMenu('menu.restore', 'restore', ROLE_ADMIN.isGranted()).endSubMenu() Anyway there a lot of possible alternatives, and the biggest problem is in specifying the right order.

Comment: Hi! Did you solve your problem? I'm very intrested in this question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InterceptorDemo:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class InterceptorDemo {

  @Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)")
  public void requestMapping() {
  }
  @Pointcut("@annotation(you.package.RequestMenuMapping)")
  public void requestMenuMapping() {
  }


  @AfterReturning("requestMapping() && equestMenuMapping()")
  public void checkServer(JoinPoint joinPoint,Object returnObj) throws Throwable {
      Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
      Model m = (Model)args[0];
      // use joinPoint get class or methd...
  }
}
```

If you want to intercept Contoller with you own, you can wirte another pointcut and `ProceedingJoinPoint` object can get what you want.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice demonstration, but unfortunately doing not what i asked about; this just intercepts all calls to `handle(..)` method (not only from `@Controller` members annotated with `@RequestMenuMapping`) and could be done better with Spring interceptors mechanism, without any AOP. What i want (again) is to get model related to some specific method with `@RequestMenuMapping` annotation, most likely in `@AfterReturning` advice, then get all methods with `@RequestMenuMapping` and put them all to model (after extracting useful data only, of course) related to this controller's method.

Comment: Yes. JoinPoint autowiring is what i needed, thank you. Rest is obvious.

Answer (score 2):

I think a better soultion would be a bean post processor to scan all controller classes for the `@RequestMenuMapping` and a `HandlerInterceptor` to add the menu items to every model map.

Answer (score 1):

Q1:
`ModelAndView` object create at `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch()`

```
// Actually invoke the handler.
mv = ha.handle(processedRequest, response, mappedHandler.getHandler());

// Do we need view name translation?
if (mv != null && !mv.hasView()) {
    mv.setViewName(getDefaultViewName(request));
}
```

So, you can intercept `handle` method after returing or override the method.

Q2:As far as i know, there are two ways getting annotation methods.

1.Use AOP:
You can declare a pointcut like this:

```
@Pointcut("@annotation(you.package.RequestMenuMapping)")
public void requestMenuMappingPountcut() {
}
```

2.Use reflection.

```
Class clazz = Class.forName(classStr);
Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
for (Method method : methods) {
    if (method.isAnnotationPresent(RequestMapping.class)
            && method.isAnnotationPresent(RequestMenuMapping.class)) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: A1.Q1: How do i get them in @AfterReturning advice? Should i maintain some singletone-registry for that or is there any more sane ways of solving it?
A2.Q1. Sure i can declare this pointcut, but my question was "How do i get **all** methods (as in java reflection Method) and classes (as in java reflection Class) annotated with @RequestMenuMapping", not "how to bind some advice to any annotated method". I need to get full list of such methods somewhere.

Comment: A2.Q2: how do i get `Class` instance in @AfterReturning advice used to advise method of this class?