# How to create a dynamic menu with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I want to create a menu from the database.  It will be part of a fragment.... how do I do that?  I have @ModelAttribute("userMenu") and a method that returns a collection of Menu objects, but it seems to return an empty set.

The code can be found at:  http://pastebin.com/RReU2DgN

So the menu would look like this:  http://prntscr.com/2blsl6  when it's all said and done.

Once I can get the menu data to the view properly, I am hoping to then be able to put it in the fragment to display the menu once a specific type of user logs in.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be helpful.  I have looked through the Spring Framework Reference and I am using the Petclinic model, but it doesn't use dynamic menus.  I've looked at the Yummy example as well and again it doesn't use dynamic menus in the way I am trying to do it.  So if there is an example you can point me to, that would be great as well.

Comment: Please embed relevant sections of your code directly into the question rather than linking to an external site.

Comment: I tried and it kept giving me a format error, so I did what I could to put the full code out there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003035/implementing-dynamic-menu-for-spring-mvc-aop-application

Answer (score 0):

You should split your issue into two.

One is retrieving menus from the db. And the other is rendering a menu from a list.

So:

Set a hardcoded list of menus into your modelattribute to be sure you can render what you like.

Once this is working its another step to get the actual menus from the database. For this you can even write a unit test or just debug into the dao.

Comment: That doesn't come close to answering the question.  I know I can pull data from the database.  The problem is this... every page will have the menu based on the fragment that displays the database records.... my question is HOW to do it based on the code that I gave and if that's not the right code, then what is the right code.

Comment: I would say it's close enough :) where is your code to get the menu dynamic atm? getMenuByType("U","A"). You say it returns an empty list. Thats just part of the problem. Can you render a menu in the style you want IF you have a proper collection of menus? If yes you go and check why the list returns null.

Comment: For the different menu per fragment: currently you use a modelattribute to load the menu. Do you know at this time already which fragment will be rendered or will this only be known during template rendering? In the first case you could use another model-/sessionattribute in the getusermenu method. Or you use the servicecall to get the menu from within the template like this: <div th:each="m,i : &{beans.menuservice(role, fragmentname)}">

Comment: As a test, I added these lines
@RequestMapping(value="/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String processHome(Model model) {
     Menu menu = new Menu();
     model.addAttribute(menu);
     return "home";
    }

When it first goes to home, it pulls no records.  If I refresh the page I see these lines in my logs:

INFO  TemplateEngine - [THYMELEAF] TEMPLATE ENGINE INITIALIZED
DEBUG MenuController - The collection for admin has 2 records
DEBUG MenuController - The collection for users has 2 records
So the first time the screen comes up the records aren't pulled.

Comment: That sounds like a cache issue on the client side. Can you check if the first call is really comming to the server and reaches you request mapping method?

Comment: I see the first call hitting the server because it initializes the template modes